# Этимология "слепой"

Tags: этимология

Ещё в XIV-XV веке слепых называли "тёмными" есть даже пара-тройка ослепленных князей  с подобным прозвищем. А когда и откуда пришло слово "слепой"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, ни в одном этимологическом словаре слово не объясняется, в некоторых его нет вообще. Слово писалось через **ять**, украинцы теперь пишут - **слiпий**. Вполне возможно предположить (в отсутствие *научного* объяснения), что слово *слепой* имеет смысл - **слипшийся**.

"Спать хочу, глаза **слипаются**, ничего уже не вижу"

Когда солнце слепит нам глаза, мы их зажмуриваем, "слепляем", "слепливаем". Версия простая и понятная даже ученым филологам.
Общеславянский корень **леп/лип**, достаточно вспомнить липу.

Comment: А нет ли какой-то связи у нашего "слипаться" (глаза) с английским sleep? Хотя вряд ли. В других языках "спать" и "слепой" совсем по-другому звучат и выглядят.

Comment: @Надюшка, в википедии пишут, что 

> От зап.-герм. \*slæpanan «спать», откуда, в частности, произошли др.-англ. slæpan, slæp и англ. sleep, др.-сакс. slapan и slap, др.-фризск. slepa и slep, ср.-нидерл. slapen и slæp, нидерл. slapen и slaap, др.-в.-нем. slafan и slaf, ср.-в.-нем. slāfen, нем. schlafen и Schlaf, готск. slepan и sleps. Восходит к праиндоевр. \*sleb- (*slāb-) «слабеть, спать». Использованы материалы Online Etymology Dictionary Дугласа Харпера; см. Список литературы.

Так что это совсем другой корень.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Фасмер дает следующее:

слепой слепо́й слеп, слепа́, сле́по, укр. слiпи́й, блр. слепы́, др.-русск., ст.-слав. слѣпъ τυφλός (Супр.), болг. сляп, сербохорв. сли̏jеп, слиjѐпа, сли̏jепо, словен. slẹ̀p, slẹ́pa, чеш., слвц. slepý, польск. ślеру, в.-луж. slеру, н.-луж. slěpy. Др. ступень чередования: ст.-слав. осльпнѫти ἀποτυφλοῦσθαι (Супр.), др.-чеш. оsl᾽núti "ослепнуть", чеш. oslnouti. Наличие аблаута гарантирует исконнослав. происхождение (Траутман, ВSW 268), хотя родство с лит. slė̃pti, slepiù, slėpiaũ "скрывать, прятать", slaptà "тайник, укрытие", лтш. slèpt, slepêt "скрыß вать" (И. Шмидт, Vok. 2, 73) сомнительно. Недостоверна также связь с гот. hleibjan "печься о к.-л." (Уленбек, РВВ 30, 291; Файст 262). •• [Неверно сближение с лит. žlìbas "подслеповатый" у Яначека ("Slavia", 24, 1955, стр. 1). Топоров ("Этимол. исследования по русск. языку", I, 1960, стр. 11 и сл.) объясняет *slěpъ из *sloi̯p-: *slĭp-, восходящего к и.-е. *lеi̯р- "намазывать", откуда и лат. lippus "подслеповатый, с воспаленными глазами". Однако не исключена возможность, что ступень редукции *slьр- не отражает чередования оi̯- : ĭ-, а произошла вторично, в условиях глаг. форм на -nǫti; см. Вайан, Gramm. соmр., 1, стр. 303; его же, Езиков. изследв. Младенов, стр. 285. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Получается, что какой-либо серьезной версии происхождения этого слова нет. Единственное, на что можно обратить внимание, что слово по ходу дела весьма старое и вполне себе общеславянское. Это можно попробовать подтвердить поиском по каким-либо древним литературным источникам. Научите меня это делать самостоятельно, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да. Тут я не проверил себя. Спасибо. "Володимеръ же слъıшавъ ӕко ӕтъ бъıс̑ Василко и слѣпленъ оужасесѧ". Это из Лаврентьевской летописи.

Летописи разных времён можно посмотреть по ссылке http://krotov.info/lib_sec/16_p/ol/noe_psrl.htm Более-менее известные произведения тоже в оригинале найти можно.

Comment: "Топоров объясняет *slěpъ из
*sloi̯p-: *slĭp-, восходящего к и.-е.
*lеi̯р- "намазывать", откуда и лат. **lippus
"подслеповатый, с воспаленными
глазами**". /////// Господа этимологи декларируют ИЕ общность языков, но не могут прямо сказать, что "**lippus** - гноящиеся, воспаленные глаза" = "**слипшиеся** от гноя глаза"... Прямое совпадение смыслов, но "мы этого не скажем"))) Липиды - жиры, кстати говоря (от греч. **lipos**); жир вроде бы **липкий**??

Comment: Остался один шажок Топорову  и Трубачеву (редактору Фасмера) - связать слово *слепой* со словами-смыслами *лепить* и *липкий*, но они его не делают! Хотя в статьях "липкий-лепить"  проводится аналогия с мазями и жирами ( lipos и др.) Характерный штрих...